# Calculating corresponding nth percentiles from a dataframe

Tags: r

```
OBS = data.frame(c(0.92, 1.00, 0.96, 0.87, 0.95))

OBS
0.92
1.00
0.96
0.87
0.95

REF = matrix(1:50, nrow=5, ncol=10)

REF
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  6  11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46
2  7  12 17 22 27 32 37 42 47
3  8  13 18 23 28 33 38 43 48
4  9  14 19 24 29 34 39 44 49
5  10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
```

OBS represent percentiles. I want to search across each row in REF and calculate the corresponding percentiles from OBS for each row. For example, this would mean calculating the 92nd percentile of the first row of REF, the 100th percentile of the second row of REF, the 96th percentile of the third row of REF etc. In this reduced example, the outcome would be:

```
OUT
42.40
47.00
46.20
43.15
47.75
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to loop over the sequence of rows of the `matrix`, get the corresponding 'OBS' and use `quantile`

```
unname(sapply(seq_len(nrow(REF)), function(i) quantile(REF[i, ], OBS[[1]][i])))
#[1] 42.40 47.00 46.20 43.15 47.75
```

---

Another option is `rowQuantiles` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
diag(rowQuantiles(REF, probs = OBS[[1]]))
#[1] 42.40 47.00 46.20 43.15 47.75
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. That solution is still running. The actual size of the datasets is large, so I wonder if there is a quicker way than looping like this?

Comment: Oh no, I certainly will recognise your effort @akrun - sorry for any offence. I really do appreciate your time and valuable advice in guiding novices like myself. I think maybe my computer is just quite slow in executing the loop but it'll get there :)

Comment: I think it will work though, so it deserves to be accepted. Thanks again @akrun

Comment: @DJ-AFC  The issue is with rowwise.  Most of the methods are optimized for columnwise.